# Jenkins does not react at changes in jenkins.xml

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a jenkins, one part of which stored at disk D and another one (war part) stored in C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\jenkins.
The lastest part has jenkins.xml file. It has --httpPort=8080 value as one of the arguments.
But if I change it to 8081 or 8090 jenkins still running at 8080 port after restarting.
Do I do smth wrong?

Comment: you restarted the jenkins server after changing the port?

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct jenkins.xml?

Comment: @Sadmi yes, I dropped proccess in console, checked that jenkins now is not availiable and executed java -jar ... again

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke yes, because searching by jenkins.xml shows 3 of them. 1 was mentition and 2 another are shortcuts from '...\AppData\...' which redirect to first one